# docker compose network not serving reqeusts from host

Tags: docker, docker-compose

[docker-compose question]

hello all! I've been stuck on this for a while so hopefully we can debug together.

I'm using docker compose to bring up three separate services.
Everything builds and comes up great. Health check for the app passes, the services make contact with each other but I can't seem to my curl my app from the host.

I've tried the following values for app.ports:

"127.0.0.1:3000:3000"
"3000:3000"
"0.0.0.0:3000:3000"

I've also tried to run this with a "host" network, but that also didn't seem to work and I don't prefer it because apparently that is not supported on Mac and my local developer environment is Macosx. The prod server is ubuntu.

And I've tried defining the default bridge netowrk explicitly:

```
networks:
    default:
        driver: bridge
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2.4"
services:
    rabbitmq:
        image: rabbitmq
        volumes:
            - ${ML_FILE_PATH}/taskqueue/config/:/etc/rabbitmq/
        environment:
            LC_ALL: "C.UTF-8"
            LANG: "C.UTF-8"
    celery-worker:
        image: ${ML_IMAGE_NAME}
        entrypoint: "celery --broker='amqp://<user>:<password>@rabbitmq:5672//' -A taskqueue.celeryapp worker --uid 1111"
        runtime: ${RUNTIME}  ## either "runc" if running locally on debug mode or "nvidia" on production with multi processors
        volumes:
            - ${ML_FILE_PATH}:/host
        depends_on:
            - rabbitmq
            - app
        environment:
            LC_ALL: "C.UTF-8"
            LANG: "C.UTF-8"
            MPLCONFIGDIR: /host/tmp
        volumes:
            - ${ML_FILE_PATH}:/host
    celery-beat:
        image: ${ML_IMAGE_NAME}
        entrypoint: "celery --broker='amqp://<user>:<password>@rabbitmq:5672//' -A taskqueue.celeryapp beat --uid 1111"
        runtime: ${RUNTIME}  ## either "runc" if running locally on debug mode or "nvidia" on production with multi processors
        depends_on:
            - rabbitmq
            - app
        environment:
            LC_ALL: "C.UTF-8"
            LANG: "C.UTF-8"
            MPLCONFIGDIR: /host/tmp
        volumes:
            - ${ML_FILE_PATH}:/host
    app:
        build: .
        entrypoint: ${ML_ENTRYPOINT}  # just starts a flask app
        image: ${ML_IMAGE_NAME}
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        expose:
            - "3000"
        volumes:
            - ${ML_FILE_PATH}:/host
        restart: always
        runtime: ${RUNTIME}
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "curl", "http:/localhost:3000/?requestType=health-check"]
            start_period: 30s
            interval: 30s
            timeout: 5s
        environment:
            SCHEDULER: "off"
            TZ: "UTC"
            LC_ALL: "C.UTF-8"
            LANG: "C.UTF-8"
```

I can hit the service from within the container as expected.

I'm not sure what I'm missing. Thanks so much for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being mostly unrelated to docker-compose.

My flask app was starting up on `127.0.0.1`. I needed to be starting it as an
[externally visible server](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application).

I just had to add --host=0.0.0.0 to my start script.

Comment: As I suspected, it was a configuration problem. Nice if it works now :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but i think you dont can route traffic from the host to containers on mac osx.

https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/networking/

Comment: yeah! I'm using that port mapping logic so I would expect to be able to curl localhost:3000 on the host (my computer) and hit my app. But no luck.

Comment: Can you map your app to port 80:3000 for testing?

Comment: yeah, just changed it and still nothing

Comment: What are you doing? curl -i http: //172.x.x.x: 3000? <-container IP? Firewall?

Comment: from host: `curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:3000/test'` --> fails, from outside host: `curl --location --request GET 'http://<host-ip>:3000/test'` --> also fails, from inside container `curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:3000/test'` --> returns as expected

Comment: I'm not sure how to tell if this is a firewall issue. Is there a file I should check?

Comment: `docker inspect <CONTAINER>` use the ip from the container, not the localhost. Docker on mac run on a virtual machine. See the link to the documentation above.

Comment: from the documentation you linked: "Docker Desktop for Mac makes whatever is running on port 80 in the container (in this case, nginx) available on port 80 of localhost"

Comment: From the output of `docker inspect <CONTAINER>`. 
            "Ports": {
                "3000/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    }
                ]
            }
`curl --location --request GET 'http://0.0.0.0:80/test` --> still fails

Comment: You can deactivate your firewall under Security -> Firewall. If that doesn't help then you've configured something wrong. That you can reach the container within the container via localhost is clear. But the port mapping doesn't seem to work properly on the host.

Comment: Turning off the firewall didn't work. But the localhost they're referring to in the documentation, and the one I'm referring to, is of the host not the container.

Comment: I just installed Docker on my Mac, otherwise I only work with Windows and Linux. On my Mac it works with a simple nginx Docker container with no issues.

Comment: I would recommend that you just install an nginx container to test if a curl will work with it. You know this is due to the configuration of your Compose project. If it still doesn't work, something is wrong with your system.

`docker pull nginx` and `docker run -p 3001:80 -d nginx` and `curl -i http://localhost:3001`

good luck :)

Comment: @GregorWedlich The `docker inspect` IP address doesn't work on MacOS or Windows hosts, and you don't ever need it on any platform.

Comment: ? docker inspect <container_id/name> work on mac ;) i dont say docker inspect ip :)